# Getting started with node.js

Tags: node.js, webrtc

How do you start a node.js server? I have tried doing the first part of a tutorial on Real Time Connection on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab)

But I cant for the life of me get localhost:2013 to work(does not exist). Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you missed something: reading the help center before asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really liked Heroku's getting started guide on Node.JS

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction